# Windows 8 BSOD and Bios Post problems

Tags: windows-8, bios, bsod

I'm having some random crashes in the last couple of days. I'll try to describe the behaviour as best as I can.

Normal pc usage (mostly browsing with chrome, sometimes playing starcraft 2 but never during the crashes). During that, random BSOD with error KERNEL_INDATA_PAGE_ERROR. When this happens, I have the following behaviour:

- If I reset the computer through the hardware reset button, the BIOS POST is extremely delayed (even 30 or more seconds) and then it just hangs there.
- If I just turn it off and then back on, the BIOS works fine and I'm back in windows 8 in a few moments.

After the last crash, I opened up the case. After turning it off and on (reboot didn't work, as described) I heard one of the fans making a strange noise, like running crazy fast. I thought about the video card fan, so I:

- Turned the pc off
- Removed the 2 PCIE power plugs from the video card (a zotac geforce gtx 560 TI)
- Turned on. The noise was still there, and of course pc didn't boot due to missing video card

Then another strange thing. I plugged the PCIE power plugs back into the video card, turned on, and it still behaved like the plugs weren't there (long beep and no video signal). I plugged them off and on about 10 times before it started working again.

I also ran memtest, wmic and chkdsk with no signs of defect on RAM and drives.

Actually I'm a bit confused. My best shots are the power supply (a Corsair CX 750 which is 7 months old) or the video card (which is one year and half old).

But I feel I'm missing something here. Any help would be appreciated, and any suggestion on any more test I can perform to try to find the culprit.

**UPDATE**

I tried to switch out my VGA with an old one (just old, not broken) and still had the crashes, so I ruled it out.

Feeling like it was either mobo or cpu, I went for the big upgrade.

What I bought new:

- Case
- Motherboard
- Ram
- CPU
- Dvd burner (as new mobo doesn't have ide bus)

What I kept:

- SSD (for windows) and 2 hard drives (for data)
- VGA
- Power supply

And guess what.. crashes still happening. Last one some minutes ago, with the following error:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000fc (0xfffffa800b1ccc00, 0x80000002244009e3, 0xfffff803c6cdb650, 0x0000000000000003)
```

I am really puzzled now. I can't say I have wasted money because the upgrade was very nice, but I haven't solved my problem, nor found the culprit.

Still any help will be immensely appreciated... thanks.

**ONE MORE UPDATE**

It keeps hanging crashing. I tried to disconnect the two hard drives, keeping only the SSD with windows on it, hoping that it was disk access to an old HDD the problem.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be it. After a reboot I got, a few minutes later:

```
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
```

So now from the "old computer" I only have the power supply, the vga (that I ruled out) and the SSD... getting closer to the culprit.. but still don't understand what's goin on.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer, and the attached code for that BSOD.  For example, if it was 0x0000007A you'd be looking at issues pulling data from the hard drive.  Yes, I know you ran chkdsk and the drive itself and the data on it appears ok.  However, if the hard drive were having issues not related to corrupted data... say, a bad PCB on the drive... it wouldn't show with chkdsk necessarily.  I'm **not** saying your issue is your drive.  I'm saying check the logs to get more information.

Comment: The bsod didn't log anything. It was stuck on "collecting data, 0%" and never got any higher. The first crash code, which I got on screen, was 0xc000000e although I can't seem to find anything useful about it.

Comment: just to be sure, there are no errors listed in the System log, in the event viewer?  None, other than the one you detailed above 0x0e?

Comment: That error is not in the system log. I got it on screen yesterday, the first time it crashed. It was the win8 screen where it tells you "your system needs to be repaired" and after that I got that bios hangup problem for the first time. The only errors I find in the system log are "Kernel-Power" due to system not shutting down properly, but those are generated after the system restarted.

Comment: then I'd have to guess it was indeed a drive problem of some sort.  That could explain the system crashing (can't get the data it needs) and the delay in the BIOS (can't access the drive properly).  But just a guess.

Comment: Doesn't explain why the bios delay is happening only on reboot (without turning off power) and not with a poweroff/poweron (where I completely turn off power for at least one moment). I even tried several subsequent reboots when happening, it hanged every time until I did the poweroff/poweron.

Comment: I have updated my post with the latest developments, and I'm even more confused than before. I'm considering an exorcism.